# Java SQL Using existing database instead of creating a new one

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I have created a database with the name "kontakt.sqlite" using sqlstudio in which a username and password are stored. Now I want to use this database in my Java project to create a simple login system, i.e. to check if the entered username and password are correct.
Only problem: When starting my program a new database with the name "kontakt.sqlite" is created instead of using the old one, therefore I get a SQL Missing database Exception. The path and the name of the database are correct, which is also proven by the fact that the new database is created in the correct location.

```
package de.hannes.db.utils;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Database {
    //Variablen
    public static final String DB_NAME = "kontakt.sqlite";
    public static final String PATH = "C:\\Users\\49160\\eclipse-workspace-neu\\KontakteFXSQL\\src\\";
    public static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:sqlite:" + PATH + DB_NAME;
    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;
    
    //Methoden
    public boolean open() {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            
            if(connection != null && statement !=null) {
                System.out.println("Connection successful");
            }
            return true;
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }


}
```

[image]

The method to query the user data:

```
public class LoginModel {
    public boolean isLogin(String username, String password, Connection connection) throws Exception {
        
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Login where username = ? and password = ? ";
        
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            return true;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        
        // Ein finally Block wird immer ausgeführt!
        finally {
        //  preparedStatement.close();
        //  connection.close();
        }
    
    }
```

The problem is that this method accesses the "newly created database" and of course does not find a TABLE "Login" with the data in it. I don't understand why a new DB is created at all. The old one should be used.

Comment: 1st thing - change explorer settings to show filename extension || 2. check the extension of the files; if equal, there must be some special character in some name(s) (not visible; similar letters but different code , ...)

Comment: Due to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms I added the tag 'sqlite' to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue with SQLite file extensions. There are plenty of them in use like *.db, *.sdb, *.sqlite, *.db3, *.s3db, .sqlite3 You name it.

The worst thing is - they are all valid. SQLite doesn't care about the extension. It checks only if the file is indeed a SQLite3 database by inspecting the magic number and the header.

**The solution:**

Check exactly the extension of the existing file created with SQLiteStudio and use the same in your Java class.